# JQuery to make either one of the date picker field required

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I have two date picker fields in my vf page. I would like to make either one of them required. I am able to make them individually required, but need help to make either one of them required.

renewaltip is the checkbox, by clicking on which both homeRenewalDates and autoRenewalDates will become visible, otherwise they will be hidden. The commented code is making them both required when they are visible, but the requirement is to make one any one of them required.

Here is the code snippet

```
$('.renewaltip').change(function () {
      if($('.renewaltip').is(":checked")) {
           $(".homeRenewalDates").show();
           $(".autoRenewalDates").show();
           /*
           $('.homeRenewalDateMonthYear').rules("add", {
                required: true
           });
           $('.autoRenewalDateMonthYear').rules("add", {
                required: true
           });
           */
     }else{
           $(".homeRenewalDates").hide();
           $(".autoRenewalDates").hide();
     }   
}).change();
```

Comment: I think you would need to add on change listener on both dates to make the either one non required once any one of them is populated on the form.
At first both of them would be required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is expected, since you're triggering required rules for both the inputs. As Sumit already mentioned in the comments you would have to validate the Home/Auto renewal dates based on their values. You can do it something like,

```
if ([$('.homeRenewalDates'), $('.autoRenewalDates')].some(el => el.val())) {
   alert('Successful!');
   //validation successful, the form input can be processed further or sent to server
} else {
   //...additional validations or ui errors
   alert('Dear User, You are required to fill at least one of Home Renewal Date or Auto Renewal date');     }
}
```

You can improve & have additional errors on ui.
I also added a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/funwithjs/4rbnu712/68/).

Comment: Thanks Sachin. This is helpful. I have the commandButton where I put the above mentioned logic in onclick, which is showing the error message / alert, but it is still redirecting to the thank you page, which I need to stop. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: I'm assuming this should be because the commandButton needs to be inside an `<apex:form></apex:form>`. You should be able to prevent it with `event.preventDefault();` I updated it in the example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/funwithjs/vyz31ux8/10/) as well.